# IntersectionObserver does not intercept elements with display contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

It looks like IntersectionObserver never considers elements with `display: contents` in the viewport.

This behaviour makes sense for `display: none` but I find it counter-intuitive for `display: contents`.

The use case of having a clean wrapper which only fetches & renders its contents on viewport intersection seems valid to me.

**Example**

```js
function callback(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

const target = document.getElementById('wrapper');

observer.observe(target);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: contents;
}

#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="loader">Loading...</div>
  <div id="content">Shown on viewport intersection</div>
</div>
```

Looking at the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box) I can see that:

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves

But still I'd expect `IntersectionObserver` to be able to detect it.

So guess it's a 2 part question:

- Is this indeed the intended behaviour or an unwanted side-effect?
- If it is the intended behaviour - what are the proper use-cases for `display-contents`?

Comment: yes, it is really sad that this doesn't work with intersection/resize observers as it seems like the perfect use-case

Comment: Wow what a bummer to discover this...